# Как объединить два одномерных массива A,B в массив C

Tags: массивы, pascalabc.net

```
A-n\
B-m\
A:1,2,3,4\
B:5,6,7,8,9\
C:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\
```

Такой ответ должен быть

Comment: Дайте подсказку, на каком языке?

Comment: Извините, PascalAbs

Answer (score 1):

Пусть корзина "А" вмещает *n* яблок, а корзина "B" - *m*, тогда для объединения вам необходимо взять корзину "C" с минимальным объемом *m+n* и по одному яблоку начать перекладывать из корзины "A" в корзину "С".

Перед тем как доставать яблоко из корзины необходимо посмотреть, а есть ли они там (т.е. яблок больше 0). Если есть, то достать очередное яблоко из корзины "А" и положить в корзину "С". Когда в корзине "А" яблок не останется нужно по одному яблоку перекладывать из корзины "B" в корзину "C". Когда в корзине "B" яблок не останется - вы выполнили задачу